# Load test data to pass into predict_classes()

Tags: keras, cnn

I am using the `Sequential` model to train a CNN. The test data are in the `submission_data_path` as .png images.

Is it possible to use `ImageDataGenerator`'s `flow_from_directory` to load test data to pass into `predict_classes()`? Since `flow_from_directory` expects images to be inside folders named by classes is there a way to achieve that?

Or else what is the most preferred way? Thanks.

This is what I am trying to do,

```
test_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_it = dataGen.flow_from_directory(submission_data_path, target_size=(64, 64), class_mode='categorical')

predictions = classifier.predict_classes(test_it)
```

Comment: This is still from TF 1.0 version, but maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991598/9524424